# What is the difference between simple consumer and high level consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka

What is the difference between simple consumer and high level consumer in Apache Kafka? I could not understand from the plenty of definitions available on internet.

Answer (score 14):

The high level consumer can manage things like offset commits and rebalancing across consumer instances in a consumer group automatically.

Using the simple consumer you have to manage partition subscription, broker leader changes and offset commits yourself. The concept of a consumer group does not exist for the simple consumer API.

Comment: But when to use what ..?

Comment: This question and answer is now kind of outdated since the "new consumer" has replaced the two older APIs. Just use the new consumer.

Comment: Yep read about that here https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/. Thank you!!  Is that stable now ..?

Comment: The new consumer is the default one, the old APIs are listed under legacy in the official documentation and personally I've seen the new consumer as mostly stable.